# Scores from an external file not ordering correctly in 'Top 5 scores list' - Python Game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a game which stores the users score in an external file, then outputs a top 5 scoreboard. However my scoreboard only works for single digit numbers, as it orders the list based on the first character on each line of the external txt file. I would like the list to order the top 5 scores and output the users name beside the score

Here is the section of the code which reproduces the problem:

```
score=5
name = input('enter your name') #enters their name
while name == "":
    print('You must enter your name')
    name = input('enter your name')
while name == " ":
    print('You must enter your name')
    name = input('enter your name')


file = open("score.txt","a") #opens a file named score.txt for append (adding on stuff)
file.write(str(score)+" ,"+name+"\n") # writes their score and name into file
file.close()  # shuts file

file=open("score.txt","r") #opens file for reading this time
readthefile = file.readlines() #reads all  the lines in the file and stoes it in the variable
sortedData = sortedData = sorted(readthefile,reverse=True)# sorted - sorts the file into numerical or alphabetical order in this case numerical. Then reverses so it goes biggest to smallest

print("\nTop 5 Scores!")#prints top 5 scores
print("Pos\tPoints, Name") #act as headers (/t is a tab)
for line in range(5): #for the top 5 lines in the file
    print(str(line+1)+"\t"+str(sortedData[line])) #prints top 3 positions . Excluding line 0.
```

Here is the output of this code:

[Scoreboad Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP2k9.png)

**Writen version of output:**
enter your nameLils

Top 5 Scores!
Pos Points, Name
1   8, Nathan

2   5 ,Lils

3   4,sally

4   19,sam

5   18,julie

What I would have expected is:

1. 19, sam
2. 18, julie
3. 15, pearl (in my 'score.txt' file but didn't make it to top 5 above)
4. 8, Nathan
5. 5, lils (or whatever name has been entered in the variable)

As you can see the code only orders the first digit so any number which has 2 digits (i.e. 10) will only be ordered by the first number (1).

Below are the contents of  my 'score.txt' file
(**before the code has been run** and there is no score with 5)

(Newline after each name)

15,pearl
4,sally
18,julie
19,sam
8,Nathan

[Score.txt contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AMSR.png)

Answer (score 2):

**You must convert the scores to integers. Python is treating them as strings and sorting them in alphabetical order**

*You can use a **python dictionary** to store the data more efficiently Here the name of the person will be key ( string ) and the score will be the value ( int )*

**If you want to save the dictionary to a file, use `pickle`**

```py
import pickle

dict = {} // the dictionary that has scores, after taking user input store here

with open('score','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(dict,f)
```

**To read the dictionary saved in a file:**

```py
with open('score','rb') as f:
    dict = pickle.load(f)
```

**To sort the elements of the dictionary by the value of score see the following snippet**

```py
scores = {
    'Harry': 54,
    'Shyam': 56,
    'Thomas': 72,
    'Neela': 48,
    'Ross': 41
}

sort_scores = sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

for i in sort_scores:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

---

- The inbuilt **sorted** function sorts the iterable based on the **key** function passed. [Learn more](https://gist.github.com/aahnik/721ce265c96e0e338cf9b6d1fcd9865d)
- **Lambdas** are one-line anonymous functions. [Learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)
- Python **Pickle module** is used for serializing and de-serializing python object structures. [Learn more](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-pickling)